# Express 4 project with dependencies which requires express 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, requirejs

I would like to develop a project (Node.js) which use the latest version of express (4.3). But I have a dependency on a module which requires express 3.3. Works that or need I use the same version on the submodules? This could maybe more a node question...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npm allows you to have dependencies which have different version of their dependencies.

So, you will be using express 4.0 (it will be placed in root `./node_modules/express`), and also a module which requires express 3.x (so, `./node_modules/your_module/node_modules/express`)